# How to fix a SQL Server connection that is painfully slow from R and Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, r

So I'm working with a connection from both R and Python to SQL Server. However, both seem to take forever when running basic queries. Can anyone help diagnose what could be wrong. How can I speed these connections up? I'd like to avoid having to use SAS for this stuff. This should return about 120,000 rows. And after about 6 minutes, it does, but I need something faster.

```
Time in SQL: 2:30
Time in R: 8:00
Time in Python: 8:00
Time in SAS: 0:10 seconds
```

**Python**

```
import os
import copy
import pyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as psql

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=****;DATABASE=****;') 

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql = ("""
select work_dt, engine, campaign, ad_group, keyword,
    matchtype, sum(impressions) as impressions,
    sum(clicks) as clicks,
    sum(cost) as cost
from abidwise_detail
where work_dt between '2014-12-03' and '2015-01-03'
group by work_dt, engine, campaign, ad_group,
keyword,matchtype;""")

df = psql.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

**R**

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )

library(RSQLServer)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLServer::SQLServer(), "****")
dbGetInfo(con)

res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select work_dt, engine, campaign, ad_group, keyword,
                   matchtype, sum(impressions) as impressions,
                   sum(clicks) as clicks,
                   sum(cost) as cost
                   from abidwise_detail
                   where work_dt between '2014-12-03' and '2014-12-05'
                   group by work_dt, engine, campaign, ad_group,
                   keyword,matchtype;")

dbHasCompleted(res) ## RETURNS FALSE !!!

df <- dbFetch(res)
head(df)

result<-list()
i=1
system.time(result[[i]]<-dbFetch(res,n=1000))
system.time(while(nrow(chunk <- dbFetch(res, n = 1000))>0){
  i<-i+1
  result[[i]]<-chunk
})
system.time(train_data<-do.call(rbind,result))
head(train_data); nrow(train_data)
```

Comment: What makes you think the problem is R or Python and not SQL Server? How long does it take to run the query directly in SQL?

Comment: good point...it takes 2 minutes and 30 seconds within sql server. R and Python is about 6 minutes

Comment: What do you mean SAS? The [statistical package](https://www.sas.com/en_us/home.html) or SQL Server's [SSAS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175609%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Naturally an SQL engine will run the fastest while clients like R and Python must convert query results into their object model. Test Python with simple cursors: `cur.fetchall()` and R without `fetch()`. Finally, 2 mins. is also long but you run an aggregate query returning 120K which means table may be much larger. Be sure to use [table indexes](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63185/listing-indexes-and-constraints). Also, check table design: use `varchar` over `text` data types.

Comment: By SAS, I mean the statistical software called SAS. I'm not a big fan of it, but it does excel with database connections.